# Range selectors in enlive

Tags: clojure, enlive

I'm trying to create a range selector, and can't seem to get off the ground.

I'm trying things like:

```
(sniptest "<div><p class='start'>Hi</p><p class='end'>There</p></div>"
      [{[:.start] [:.end]}] (content "Hello"))
```

And that just returns the supplied html. I'd expect it to return a div with the body "Hello".

How do I do this?

**EDIT**

Just to be more concise, this is what I've done with deftemplate and a real html file:

*HTML*

```
<html>
<head>
  <title></title>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Not hello</h1>

<div class="start">
 foo
 </div>

 <div class="end">
    bar
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

*CLJ*

```
(ns compojure-blog-test.views.landing-page
  (:require [net.cgrand.enlive-html :as html]))

(html/deftemplate landing-page "compojure_blog_test/views/landing_page.html"
  [blogs]
  {[:.start] [:.end]} (html/content "Blah blah"))
```

I'm following along with [this tutorial](https://github.com/swannodette/enlive-tutorial), but it uses a snippet to match ranges. Is this neccesary?

Is it possible to test these out with just `sniptest`?

Comment: I may be misunderstanding, though, did you mean (content "Hi") instead of (content "Hello") ?

Comment: No, I thought content would replace the matched content. Is this wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are called "fragment selectors" in enlive parlance and unfortunatly for your purposes they don't support `content` directly, though if you wrap them in a `clone-for` you can get the same effect.

```
user> (require '[net.cgrand.enlive-html :as html])
nil
user> (html/sniptest "<div>
                        <p class='before'>before</p>
                        <p class='start'>Hi</p>
                        <p class='end'>There</p>
                        <p class='after'>after</p>
                        <p class='end'>last</p>
                      </div>"
                     {[:.start] [:.end]} (html/clone-for [m ["Hello"]]
                                            [:p] (html/content m)))
"<div>
   <p class=\"before\">before</p>
   <p class=\"start\">Hello</p>
   <p class=\"end\">Hello</p>
   <p class=\"after\">after</p>
   <p class=\"end\">last</p>
 </div>"
```

This allows you to do more interesting things based on the position in the fragment

```
user> (html/sniptest "<div>
                        <p class='before'>before</p>
                        <p class='start'>Hi</p>
                        <p class='end'>There</p>
                        <p class='after'>after</p>
                        <p class='end'>last</p>
                     </div>"
    {[:.start] [:.end]} (html/clone-for [m [["Hello" "Sir"]]]
                           [:p.start] (html/content (first m))
                           [:p.end]   (html/content (last m))))
"<div>
  <p class=\"before\">before</p>
  <p class=\"start\">Hello</p>
  <p class=\"end\">Sir</p>
  <p class=\"after\">after</p>
  <p class=\"end\">last</p>
 </div>"
```

You can also use `do->` instead of `clone-for`:

```
user> (html/sniptest "<div>
                        <p class='before'>before</p>
                        <p class='start'>Hi</p>
                        <p class='end'>There</p>
                        <p class='after'>after</p>
                        <p class='end'>last</p>
                      </div>"
    {[:.start] [:.end]} (html/do-> (html/content "Hello")))
"<div>
   <p class=\"before\">before</p>
   <p class=\"start\">Hello</p>
   <p class=\"end\">Hello</p>
   <p class=\"after\">after</p>
   <p class=\"end\">last</p>
</div>"
```

Comment: Thanks, it didn't click for me that I would need to match the :.start inside the clone for. But it makes perfect sense now :).