# Extracting consecutive html fragments with enlive

Tags: clojure, enlive

I need to scrape html that has the following form:

```
<div id='content'>
    <h3>Headline1</h3>
    <div>Text1</div>
    <div>Text2</div>
    <div>Text3</div>
    <h3>Headline2</h3>
    <div>Text4</div>
    <div>Text5</div>
    <h3>Headline3</h3>
    <div>Text6</div>
    <div>... and so on ...</div>
</div>
```

I need to get the content between the  headline tags as separate chunks. So from one headline up to the next. Unfortunately there is no container tag for the desired ranges.

I tried the fragment selector `{[:h3] [:h3]}` but somehow this only returns all h3 tags, without the tags in between them:
    `(({:tag :h3, :attrs nil, :content ("Headline1")}) ({:tag :h3, :attrs nil, :content ("Headline2")}) ({:tag :h3, :attrs nil, :content ("Headline3")}))`

What does work, is `{[[:h3 (html/nth-of-type 1)]] [[:h3 (html/nth-of-type 2)]]}`. This gives me all of the html between the first and second h3-tag. However this does not give me all of the desired chunks with one selector.

Can enlive do this at all or should I resort to a regular expression?

Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer help?: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17157780/range-selectors-in-enlive

PS you cannot use regular expression to parse HTML: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags If you try you may wake the ancient ones ;-)

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't seem to help. When I select with {[:h3] [:h3]} I only get the h3-tags, but not the nodes in between them.

Comment: If you add an html snippet and your selector we may be able to write one that matches. Bonus points if you include the output you are getting now.

Comment: Hi, I've edited the post with a snippet and a more detailed description. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select out everything in div.content and then partition them base upon tag.

There is a more general concept here of separating a sequence of things into segments by identifying which things are separators and which are not:

```
(defn separate*
  "Produces a sequence of (parent child*)*, coll must start with a parent"
  [child? coll]
  (lazy-seq
   (when-let [s (seq coll)]
     (let [run (cons (first s)
                     (take-while child? (next s)))]
       (cons run (separate* child? (drop (count run) s)))))))
```

Very similar to `partition-by`, but always splits on parent:

```
(partition-by keyword? [:foo 1 2 3 :bar :baz 4 5])
;; => ((:foo) (1 2 3) (:bar :baz) (4 5))

(separate* (compliment keyword?) [:foo 1 2 3 :bar :baz 4 5])
;; => ((:foo 1 2 3) (:bar) (:baz 4 5))
```

If you want to handle when there is no leading title:

```
(defn separate
  [parent? coll]
  (when-let [s (seq coll)]
    (if (parent? (first coll))
      (separate* (complement parent?) coll)
      (let [child? (complement parent?)
            run (take-while child? s)]
        (cons (cons nil run)
              (separate* child? (drop (count run) s)))))))

(separate keyword? [1 2 :foo 3 4])
;; => ((nil 1 2) (:foo 3 4))
```

And returning to the problem at hand:

```
(def x [{:tag :h3 :content "1"}
        {:tag :div :content "A"}
        {:tag :div :content "B"}
        {:tag :h3 :content "2"}
        {:tag :div :content "C"}
        {:tag :div :content "D"}])

(def sections (separate #(= :h3 (:tag %)) x))
=> (({:content "1", :tag :h3}
     {:content "A", :tag :div
     {:content "B", :tag :div})
    ({:content "2", :tag :h3}
     {:content "C", :tag :div}
     {:content "D", :tag :div}))
```

If we don't care to retain the content of the h3 titles:

```
(map rest sections)
=> (({:content "A", :tag :div} {:content "B", :tag :div})
    ({:content "C", :tag :div} {:content "D", :tag :div}))
```

Comment: Looks awesome. I'll test it as soon as I find some time... Thanks!